# Using a role-play to teach ohm's law

Tags: electricity, education

An education research project: can a role-play be used to help understand Ohm's Law?
I need to have this analogy checked for scientific validity. A group of 25 primary children will participate, with two year 6/7 children as the directors.

1. The circuit will be the inside of two lines of sticky tape on the floor, 800mm wide.
2. The battery will be a fixed beat from a keyboard. When the music plays, children must move clockwise. When the music stops, they can drift around but they can't touch each other. They have to stay evenly distributed around the circuit when the music is off. They must take one step for each beat of the music. If the tempo is increased, they must take more steps in less time.
3. The circuit will include copper wire (the sticky tape), a lightbulb (a narrowed area of stick tape, 100mm wide) and the battery (the stereo).
4. Half the children will be free electrons. The other half will be copper atoms.
5. The copper atoms must distribute themselves evenly around the circuit inside the sticky tape.
6. When the music plays, the free electrons must walk around and past the copper atoms without touching them or another free electron.

The purpose is to help them see that:
1. There are always free elctrons drifting inside copper wire
2. A battery does not make electricity, only pushes it
3. Electrons bunch up going into a resistor, and space out on the other side
4. The year 6/7 children will be given extra theory before the role play. They are the subjects of the experiment, and if the younger children start to do something that is not in keeping with ohm's law, they must correct the behaviour.

Comment: If this question interests you, consider supporting the [Science Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79366/science-educators) proposal.